# How to apply a formula to a certain cell in Google Sheets when row is updated and a certain cell has a certain value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, zapier, google-sheets-macros

I have a Google Sheet is being updated through two channels, an App through Appsheet, and an automated workflow from Zapier. Both add new rows for new bookings. The updates which come through the App work perfect, this is the main way of working. Now, I want to add information coming in through Zapier. Problem is that not all the information coming from Zapier is in the right format.

Please see the Sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uZ2YAbVjVAF9Ki4ze4mzeeIZjbLLs0aJjf5hh0r1v8w/edit?usp=sharing).

If the data comes through Zapier, a new row will be created by Zapier and all columns except for Column C 'Driver ID'. I need this cell to be automatically updated. I can do this with an IndexMatch linking to another sheet with an overview of all the names and ID's. However, Zapier will always create a new row and therefore there will be no formula.

If data comes in through Appsheet all columns will be filled out except for Column E 'Driver Name'. There is no need for this since this information is already included in the Driver ID.

What I want to do is, apply a formula to Column C, if a value appears in Column E. If no value appears in Column E than there is no need for a formula in Column C. How can I trigger the placement of an (IndexMatch) formula for the cell when a certain cell has a text-value?

Comment: Depending on the method zapier uses, you may or may not be able to use an "on edit" or "on change" trigger to detect the data addition. You might instead prefer to just use a time-based trigger to read the sheet's values and set a formula if needed.

Comment: You could use an [arrayformula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Comment: I don't know what time frames you need to adjust to in this case, but if they are not too tight, and the flow of updates from your Appsheets script is enough, you could use that as the Trigger. Every time you add a row from the script, you verify all previous rows and check whether there is a Zapier entry or not. You could use the PropertiesService to mark the last row that was updated, so you don't have to loop from the beginning every single time.